# The Safari instance is already paired with another WebDriver session

Tags: python, selenium, safari

I am doing selenium webdriver automation in Python. I have two functions i.e. test cases in one class.
i.e. def test_Test1 and def test_Test2.
Problem is, while running the 1st test case i.e. "test_Test1" in Safari, my pycharm is throwing me an execption on executing 2nd test case i.e. "test_Test2" i.e

```
The Safari instance is already paired with another WebDriver session.
```

What is the possible solution of this and what is the reason of this?

Comment: Are you running in parallel? Some browsers only allow 1 instance at a time afaik, unless you are running them on multiple machines in a selenium grid or similar setup.

Comment: Check out the comments in [this issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5057).